# Insert 4-column rows into database table from a flat array with a size divisible by four

Tags: php, arrays, loops, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I have an array like below which is generated by exploding a user-supplied string:

```
// $array = explode(',' $_POST['arrCheckTrans']);
$array = [
    '098A',
    'mike',
    'Street17',
    'LA',
    '07AA',
    'steve',
    'Street14',
    'LA'
];
```

I need to isolate four elements at a time and use those sets of values to make iterated INSERT queries.

Below is my code:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "checktransfertmp") {

   $arrCheckTrans = $_POST['arrCheckTrans'];
   
   $trans = explode(",", $arrCheckTrans);
   
   $length = count($trans);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       print $trans[$i];
   }
}
```

How can I make run insert queries for each set of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk).

```
$chunks = array_chunk($trans, 4);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
  // Build your insert string
}
```

To build your insert string (rather than doing multiple queries) you could do something like:

```
$insertString  = 'INSERT INTO myTable(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ';

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $insertString .= ' (' . implode(', ', array_map('escape_function', $chunk)) . ',';
}

$insertString = substr($insertString, 0, -1);
```

- Note to use a real escape function like `mysqli_real_escape_function`, or `array($pdoLink, 'escape')`.

Answer (score 2):

Upon exploding the submitted string on its commas, you only need to chunk the values into rows of 4 elements, then securely insert them into your database.

Code: ([PHPize MySQLi Demo](https://phpize.online/s/F4))

```
$array = [
    '098A',
    'mike',
    'Street17',
    'LA',
    '07AA',
    'steve',
    'Street14',
    'LA'
];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
foreach (array_chunk($array, 4) as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
var_export(
    $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM my_table')->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
);
```

---

or virtually the same code: ([PHPize PDO Demo](https://phpize.online/s/w4))

```
$array = [
    '098A',
    'mike',
    'Street17',
    'LA',
    '07AA',
    'steve',
    'Street14',
    'LA'
];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
foreach (array_chunk($array, 4) as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
var_export(
    $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM my_table')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split an array into chunks, and insert statement can insert multiple rows with query like this:

```
$output = array_chunk( $trans, 4 );
foreach ( $output as $key => $value ) {
    $output[$key] = '(' . implode( ',', $value ) . ')';
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c,d) VALUES ' . implode( ',', $output );

// INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c,d) VALUES (098A,mike,Street17,LA),(07AA,steve,Street14,LA) 
echo $query;
```

Comment: Be careful as this is currently vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: It is just a demonstration of how to build a query, of course that all values used in that query should be escaped.